Mercadolibre API - Editar publicación de inmueble
Estoy integrándome con el API de Mercadolibre para publicar inmuebles. La publicación funciona sin problemas, por ejemplo enviando un POST a https://api.mercadolibre.com/items con el payload
{
    "category_id": "MLC157520",
    "title":"Prueba no ofertar",
    "price": 10000,
    "currency_id": "CLF",
    "available_quantity": 1,
    "buying_mode": "classified",
    "listing_type_id": "silver",
    "condition": "not_specified",
    "pictures": [{
        "source": "http://mla-d2-p.mlstatic.com/item-de-test-no-ofertar-543605-MLA25041518406_092016-O.jpg?square=false"
    }],
    
    "location": {
        "address_line": "Asturias 101",
        "zip_code": "7570819",
        "neighborhood": {
            "id": "TVhYTWV0cm8gRXNjdWVsYSBNaWxpdGFyVFV4R"
        },
        "latitude": -33.415884, 
        "longitude": -70.585425
    },
    "attributes": [{
            "id": "ROOMS",
            "value_name": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "FULL_BATHROOMS",
            "value_name": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "PARKING_LOTS",
            "value_name": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "BEDROOMS",
            "value_name": "4"
        },
        {
            "id": "COVERED_AREA",
            "value_name": "50 m²"
        },
        {
            "id": "TOTAL_AREA",
            "value_name": "70 m²"
        }
    ]
}

Sin embargo, esta publicación queda en estado pendiente de pago, y si intento actualizarla, por ejemplo mediante un PUT a https://api.mercadolibre.com/items/MLC2648925210 con el payload
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "id": "ROOMS",
            "value_name": "3"
        }
    ]
}

recibo un error:
{
    "message": "Cannot update item MLC2648925210 [status:payment_required, has_bids:false]",
    "error": "validation_error",
    "status": 400,
    "cause": [
        {
            "department": "items",
            "cause_id": 247,
            "type": "error",
            "code": "item.attributes.not_modifiable",
            "references": [
                "attributes"
            ],
            "message": "attributes is not modifiable."
        }
    ]
}

Sin embargo, sí me deja actualizar la descripción haciendo PUT a https://api.mercadolibre.com/items/MLC2648925210
Hice la prueba con otro producto de ejemplo en una categoría no relacionada con inmuebles y me deja modificar los atributos sin problema.
Si el error que obtengo en la respuesta se debe a que estoy probando con una categoría que requiere pago por publicación... cómo se supone que realice las pruebas de integración?

Eso.. deberias preguntarselo a ellos... recuerda, no somos soporte de mercado libre ;)

Finalmente en una sección no tan evidente de la documentación, llamada
Configurar paquete para usuario de prueba descubrí que el API no es 100% autoatendido sino que requiere abrir un ticket de soporte para que los test users puedan publicar sin que las publicaciones queden en estado "pago pendiente".
